# One column abstract into two column paper

Tags: multicol

I'm trying to put my paper into the template two-column of springer "svjour3".I had a problem in making the abstract in one column and the other into two-column. I used the code below, but the problem that the affiliation of authors doesn't appear when I remove the make title just before the abstract, when I add it the abstract will be on the next page, and the affiliations appear. Please I need your help.

```
\twocolumn[

\begin{@twocolumnfalse}

\maketitle


\begin{abstract}
Insert your abstract here. Include keywords, PACS and mathematical
subject classification numbers as needed.
\keywords{First keyword \and Second keyword \and More}
% \PACS{PACS code1 \and PACS code2 \and more}
% \subclass{MSC code1 \and MSC code2 \and more}
\end{abstract}

\end{@twocolumnfalse}

]
```

Comment: What do you want exactly? To have the abstract using the whole text width as though the paper was in single column mode?

Comment: I want to make the abstract in one column and the article in two columns.

Comment: So you mean, say, the abstract entirely in the first column?

Comment: Exactly. When I try the above code the affiliation doesn't appear.

Comment: What document class are you using?

Comment: \documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}

Comment: Ok. Please be so kind to this community and EDIT your question, completing your code starting with `\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3} ` and ending with `\end{document}`. It should compile, BTW ... // Thank you